# Laravel model: instance or relationship?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm not a professional programmer,  so I don't know that I'm describing this very well.

Eloquent relationships are established in the model, using syntax and functions such as `... - >belongsTo..` etc.

Behind these models,  are tables in my database.

In my (laravel) application, I have a logged in user who needs certain information about other users.  At the end of the day,  they're all just users, persisting in the user's table.

So when I use a relationship to another object, (e.g. car) all is good. When I try use a relationship to another user I get errors like `Cannot redeclare class App\Models\User.`

I think I'm misunderstanding something here.

I get the feeling maybe I should be 'instantiating' another version of my User (as 'manager') ... But do I really need to? It's more of a lookup than anything else. I'm not sure I would even know how to do that.

Some pointers please?

Comment: Could you provide some code? Apparently you have more than one declaration of User class

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created two distinct "User" models:

```
// /app/User.php:

<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User');
    }
}


// /app/models/User.php:

<?php namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Instead you want to have a single class which belongs to itself:

```
// /app/User.php:

<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function parent() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function children() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then in your database make sure that the users table has a `user_id` property (edit `database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`):

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Now you can attach users to one another:

```
<?php

$manager = new User();
$employeeOne = new User();
$employeeTwo = new User();

$manager->children()->saveMany([
    $employeeOne,
    $employeeTwo
]);

dd( $employeeTwo->parent->name ); // Manager's name
```